# Removing file extensions & redirecting to index page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

So I am trying to get my site to remove all file extensions so instead of https://multimap.xyz/error/id.php?=... it will just be https://multimap.xyz/error/id?=... . Simarly I should be able to do https://multimap.xyz/mail/index.php and it removes the trailing index.php  to result in just https://multimap.xyz/mail/.

I'm trying to achieve this with both .php and .html file extensions and indexes and using .htaccess and this is what I have so far

```
php_flag display_errors off
ErrorDocument 404 https://multimap.xyz/error/id?=404
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This works well for removing file extensions. So the .../error/id?=... works perfectly. However when trying to access https://multimap.xyz/mail/ it shows me an error page saying

> The requested URL /email/.php was not found on this server.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure this needs tag [tag:php]

Comment: Did you mean to say https://multimap.xyz/mail/ shows The requested URL /mail/.php was not found on this server.  ?

Comment: You could add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` to only rewrite it to files that exist for instance. Or do what's more maintainable: just use a bootstrap file as `FallbackResource`, and use logic in the language of your choice.

Comment: Do be aware that the 2 RewriteConds do not apply to the second RewriteRule, if you want those to apply, add them again.

Comment: yes, going to the url /email/ shows the error posted, as it looks like its trying to find /email/.php not /email/index.php

Answer (score 1):

You should check presence of `.html` and `.php` file before their rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index|(\S+?))\.(?:php|html)[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Simply wonderful.

Comment: However, if the file does not exist, it gives me an Internal 500 error rather than redirect to my 404  ErrorDocument 404 /404

Comment: Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before both of the last rules